# Counting number of functions in modular arithmetic

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

$ f(kx \mod  p) \equiv kf(x) \mod p$ for some function $f$ defined as $f: \{0,1,....p-1\} \rightarrow \{0,1,....p-1\} $, where $p$ is an odd prime and $k$ lies in the range $[0,p-1]$ (both $p$ and $k$ are fixed integers).

We have to find the number of distinct functions, $f$, for which this relationship is satisfied (the relationship should be satisfied for any $x \in [0,p-1]$).

I've found the answer for $k=0$ and $k=1$ (it comes out to be $p^{p-1}$ and $p^{p}$ respectively, but I want a clever way to generalize it.

Comment: Please write  mod p  as  $ \mod{p }$  and you will get a nice formate!

Comment: How did you get   $p^p $ for  the case  $k=1$, I think it should be  $p!$

Comment: @Nizar it won't be p! because a function can take the same values at different points i.e, different elements in the domain can have same outputs- the only condition being that all the elements in the domain are mapped.

Comment: Okay  I get it, thank you for making the idea clear, I suppose your function should be bijective.

Answer (score 0):

First note that $f(0)\equiv kf(0)\pmod{p}$, so $f(0)\equiv 0$ since $k > 1$. Now let's assume that $x\not\equiv0$.

The key here is to look at powers of $k$ modulo $p$. Define $\text{ord}_p(k)$, the order of $k$ modulo $p$, to be the least positive integer $n$ such that $k^n\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. (Exercise: show that $\text{ord}_p(k)$ exists, and that it divides $p-1$)

Let $f(1)\equiv c_0\pmod{p}$; there are $p$ ways to choose this. Now the values of $f(k),f(k^2),\cdots,f(k^{\text{ord}_p(k)})$ are determined: they are $kc_0,k^2c_0,\cdots,c_0$, respectively. Since $k^{\text{ord}_p(k)}\equiv1$, the powers of $k$ will repeat after $k^{\text{ord}_p(k)}$, so these are the **only** values that are determined.

(For notation's sake, set $a_0=1$)

If there are any nonzero remainders not in the set $\{k^n\pmod{p}|n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, pick the smallest one, say $a_1$. Set $f(a_1)\equiv c_1\pmod{p}$; again, there are $p$ ways to do this. Now the values of $f(a_1k),f(a_1k^2),\cdots,f(a_1k^{\text{ord}_p(k)})$ are determined; again, these are the only values that are determined

Next we can pick the smallest nonzero value $a_2$ not in the set $\{k^n,a_1k^n\pmod{p}|n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, if such a value exists, and choose $f(a_2)$. We can continue this process until all the values of the function are determined.

How many ways are there to perform the algorithm above? Each time we pick an $a_i$, we determine the function at $\text{ord}_p(k)$ values. We need to show that these are distinct. First, suppose for the sake of contradiction that $a_i k^n\equiv a_ik^m\pmod{p}$ for some distinct $n,m\in\{1,2,\cdots,\text{ord}_p(k)\}$. Without loss of generality let $n < m$. Since $k$ is invertible, $a_i\equiv a_ik^{m-n}\pmod{p}$. Since $a_i$ is invertible, $1\equiv k^{m-n}$. However, by the definition of order we must then have that $m-n\ge \text{ord}_p(k)$, a contradiction from the bounds on $m,n$.

Next suppose for the sake of contradiction that we determined the same value for distinct $a_i,a_j$. Then for some $n,m$ we have that $a_i k^n\equiv a_jk^m$. Without loss of generality suppose $i< j$. Then $a_i k^{n-m}\equiv a_j$. However, by definition we chose $a_j$ so that it was not in the set $\{k^n,a_1k^n,\cdots,a_i k^n,\cdots,a_{j-1}k^n|n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, a contradiction.

Therefore, each time we determine $f(a_i)$, we determine $f$ on $\text{ord}_p(k)$ new, distinct values. We must stop after we have determined $p-1$ values, or when we have determined $\dfrac{p-1}{\text{ord}_p(k)}$ of the $a_i$s. Since we have $p$ choices for each value of $f(a_i)$, we have $p^{\frac{p-1}{\text{ord}_p(k)}}$ total functions $f$, as long as $k > 1$.